# How to use Go slice when calling WebAssembly code in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, webassembly

I want to calculate the sum of an array using WebAssembly in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"

    wasm "github.com/wasmerio/go-ext-wasm/wasmer"
)

const length int32 = 4

func main() {
    // Instantiate the module.
    wasmbyte, _ := wasm.ReadBytes("test.wasm")
    instance, _ := wasm.NewInstance(wasmbyte)
    defer instance.Close()
    hasmemory := instance.HasMemory()
    fmt.Println("it has memory:", (hasmemory))

    a := []int32{1, 2, 3, 4}
    var i int32
    var ptr [length]*int32

    for i = 0; i < length; i++ {
        ptr[i] = &a[i]
        fmt.Printf("Value of a[%d] = %d\n", i, *ptr[i])

        // pass int value
        // lengths := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(a)
        // fmt.Printf("customLen=%d\n", int32(lengths))
        // result := int32(lengths)

        allocateResult, err := instance.Exports["bar"](*ptr[i], length)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error is here", err)
        }

        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(instance.Memory.Data()[0:4], uint32(length))

        inputPointer := allocateResult.ToI32()

        //  Write the subject into the memory.
        memory := instance.Memory.Data()[inputPointer:]
        binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(memory)

        resp := hex.EncodeToString(memory)
        fmt.Println("resp:", resp)

    }
}
```

But this code is not giving me the expected result. Logic for my code is to calculate the sum of an array. Values to the array is giving during runtime.
What changes I need to do?

My rust code looks like this

```rust
use std::os::raw::c_int;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn bar(my_array: *const c_int, length: c_int) -> *mut c_int{
    let slice = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(my_array, length as usize) };
    let resp: i32 = slice.iter().sum();

    resp as *mut c_int
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy data to WebAssembly memory (for example WebAssembly memory address 0):

```
    a := []int32{10, 20, 30, 40}
    // Copy data to wasm memory:
    bytes := instance.Memory.Data()
    for i, v := range a {
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(bytes[4*i:], uint32(v))
    }
```

Get the `bar` exported function from the WebAssembly instance:

```
    bar := instance.Exports["bar"]
```

Call that exported function with WebAssembly memory address and length:

```
    result, err := bar(0, 4)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(result)
```

The `main.go` file:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"

    wasm "github.com/wasmerio/go-ext-wasm/wasmer"
)

func main() {
    // Instantiate the module.
    wasmbyte, err := wasm.ReadBytes("test.wasm")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    instance, err := wasm.NewInstance(wasmbyte)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer instance.Close()
    hasmemory := instance.HasMemory()
    fmt.Println("it has memory:", hasmemory)

    a := []int32{10, 20, 30, 40}
    // Copy data to wasm memory:
    bytes := instance.Memory.Data()
    for i, v := range a {
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(bytes[4*i:], uint32(v))
    }

    bar := instance.Exports["bar"]

    result, err := bar(0, 4)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Output (`go run main.go`):

```
it has memory: true
100
```

And the following `src/lib.rs` file has the same wasm binary (since Rust slice has only pointer and length):

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn bar(slice: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    slice.iter().sum()
}
```

Convert to `test.wasm`:

```sh
rustc --target wasm32-unknown-unknown -O --crate-type=cdylib src/lib.rs  -o test.wasm
```

Output converted to [`test.wat`](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt) (`wasm2wat test.wasm -o test.wat`) to see the function `$bar` arguments (`param i32 i32`):

```
(module
  (type (;0;) (func (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (func $bar (type 0) (param i32 i32) (result i32)
    (local i32)
    block  ;; label = @1
      local.get 1
      br_if 0 (;@1;)
      i32.const 0
      return
    end
    local.get 1
    i32.const 2
    i32.shl
    local.set 2
    i32.const 0
    local.set 1
    loop  ;; label = @1
      local.get 0
      i32.load
      local.get 1
      i32.add
      local.set 1
      local.get 0
      i32.const 4
      i32.add
      local.set 0
      local.get 2
      i32.const -4
      i32.add
      local.tee 2
      br_if 0 (;@1;)
    end
    local.get 1)
  (table (;0;) 1 1 funcref)
  (memory (;0;) 16)
  (global (;0;) (mut i32) (i32.const 1048576))
  (global (;1;) i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (global (;2;) i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (export "memory" (memory 0))
  (export "bar" (func $bar))
  (export "__data_end" (global 1))
  (export "__heap_base" (global 2)))
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Why I need to add rust code in lib.rs (can't I use main.rs) ?  And want to use `cargo build --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown`

Comment: yup, both codes are working. but using this command `rustc --target wasm32-unknown-unknown -O --crate-type=cdylib src/lib.rs  -o test.wasm` (when code in `lib.rs`).
I'm wondering why its not working for `cargo build`

Comment: I added that and ran `cargo build` still when I run go code result is 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209906/discussion-between-achala-and-wasmup).